# Reading user details from wix database - WIX Developer Mode

Tags: javascript, velo

I am trying to write a custom Wix script, that does the following :

I am using Wix 'Member Area'. I want the script on the member page to works in the following flow:

(1) After user login. the script picks the user details from Wix database like his e-mail, para1, para2, etc.

(2) Use the collected details in the previous step and create an iframe code like

```html
<iframe = src=https://externalwebsite.com/app?email=user@gmail.com&para1=abc&para2=xyz ></iframe>
```

(3) insert this iframe code into a embedded element on the page like:

```html
<div id="iframe-code-here">
    //insert code here
</div>
```

The iframe when loads then it pulls information for this client from an external website via the parameters passed in URL and displays.

I am new to Wix developer mode. Your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of how to accomplish this (numbers relate to the numbers in your question):

1. Use the [`onLogin`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users/onlogin) event to [query](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/query) one of the members collections (e.g. [PrivateMembersData](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-wix-members-privatemembersdata-collection-fields)).
2. Use the data returned from the query to build your URL.
3. Set the [`src`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent/src) property of an HTML Element that you've added to your page to the URL you built.